# Default behaviour of \tkzMarkAngle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I recently upgraded tkz-euclide to the newest version and I noticed a different behaviour of `\tkzMarkAngle` with respect to the past. Now a single mark is added to angles even when the command `mark=|` is not specified. Is it possible to tell tkz-euclide in the preamble to use the option `mark=none` as default with `\tkzMarkAngle`?

For example in a document like this

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
%
%---------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{x=1cm,y=1cm,z=1cm}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,3){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=red,thick,mark=|](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=blue,thick](C,B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The angle in red should have the mark but the angle in blue should not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as the manual says the default mark is `none`, there is a mistake in either the manual or the code. I'll report it on GitHub later.

But you can set the default with `\tikzset{/tkzmkangle/mark=none}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzset{
 x=1cm,y=1cm,z=1cm,
 /tkzmkangle/mark=none %<-- add this
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,3){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=red,thick,mark=|](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=blue,thick](C,B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It’s a mistake in the manual. But I don’t know why I made this choice. I think « none » is the good default. I will change that in the next version.

Comment: Thank you very much to you and to Alain.

Comment: Just wondering if there is any update -- is this now fixed?

Comment: @Mathemanic No, the last update on CTAN was April 2020 (https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/tkz-euclide).