# Circle diagram made with tkz-euclide renders differently in TeX Live 2018 versus TeX Live 2020

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, incompatibility, tkz-euclide

I have another question similar to [my last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570132/triangle-diagram-made-with-tkz-euclide-renders-in-tex-live-2018-but-not-2020) about 2018 -> 2020 `tkz-euclide` compatibility changes.

I have a circle diagram that compiles and renders perfectly in Overleaf (TeX Live 2018):

[image]

Here is the code that compiles successfully:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\printanswers
\usepackage{gensymb} %for degree symbol
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,patterns,positioning,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} %For polygon nodes, see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/node-shapes/
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

%Needed to resolve conflict between tkz-euclide and thmtools, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456029/thmtools-and-tkz-euclide-conflict
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
%\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%%% patch tkz-tools-base.tex
\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin % don't undef \@xa or thmtools will be upset
\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax\undef\@xb
\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin\undef\@ya
\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax\undef\@yb
\patchcmd{\tkz@Init}
 {\global\let\@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {\global\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\tkz@Grid}
 {(\@xa,\@ya)(\@xb,\@yb)}
 {(\tkz@g@xa,\tkz@g@ya)(\tkz@g@xb,\tkz@g@yb)}
 {}{}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}

\part Find:
%from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23290
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:O](0:0){O}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below left:A](230:2){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below right:B](310:2){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:C](90:2){C}
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=10](O,A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\tkzDrawPolygon(C,A,O,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75](A,O,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,font=\small](A,O,B){80\degree}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75](A,C,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,font=\small](A,C,B){$\alpha$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\part Evaluate the unknown arc and angle measures.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] %from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21949
\tkzDefPoint (0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint (2,0){P}
\tkzDefPoint (1,0){C}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](O){$O$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](P){$P$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,1cm)
\tkzTangent[from with R=P](O,1cm) \tkzGetPoints{T1}{T2}
\tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 0](O,T1 O,T2 O,P)
\tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 0.5](P,T1 P,T2)
\tkzLabelPoint[above](T1){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](T2){$B$}
\tkzDrawArc[R with nodes,](P,0.5)(T1,T2)
%\draw (T1) node[above right] {$P(\alpha)=(a\,\cos\alpha,a\,\sin\alpha)$};
%\draw (T2) node[below right] {$Q(\alpha)=(a\,\cos\beta,a\,\sin\beta)$};
\draw (P) +(165:0.6) node {$25\degree$};
%\draw (P) +(195:0.6) node {$25\degree$};
\tkzLabelSegment[above right](O,A){$6$ cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

However if you change the TeX Live distribution from 2018 to 2020, it renders differently and Overleaf spits some errors:

[image]

[image]

I learned from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529550/latex-cant-find-file-tkz-obj-angles-tex) that `\usetkzobj{all}` shouldn't be used with recent tkz-euclide. Commenting this line in the 2020 distribution fixes some but not all issues.

Some (undesired changes):

1. In 1st diagram, geometric points are very large
2. In 1st diagram, angles have a "tick mark" in them
3. In 2nd diagram, tangent lines to circle disappeared

Any ideas how to fix these issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `\usetkzobj{all}` should be removed, in the new version it gives an error. (Sorry, didn't see you had mentioned that, but it wasn't commented out in the code.)

Second, `\tkzTangent` should be `\tkzDefTangent`

That fixes the errors. For the undesired changes:

1. if the dots are too large, just change the size in `\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=10](O,A,B,C)`, e.g. `size=5`.
2. [Default behaviour of \tkzMarkAngle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544730/default-behaviour-of-tkzmarkangle/544732#544732)
3. See `\tkzDefTangent` above.

Complete code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\printanswers
\usepackage{gensymb} %for degree symbol
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,patterns,positioning,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} %For polygon nodes, see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/node-shapes/
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

%Needed to resolve conflict between tkz-euclide and thmtools, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456029/thmtools-and-tkz-euclide-conflict
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzset{/tkzmkangle/mark=none}  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544732
%\usetkzobj{all} % <-- don't use this with the new version
%\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%%% patch tkz-tools-base.tex
\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin % don't undef \@xa or thmtools will be upset
\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax\undef\@xb
\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin\undef\@ya
\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax\undef\@yb
\patchcmd{\tkz@Init}
 {\global\let\@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {\global\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\tkz@Grid}
 {(\@xa,\@ya)(\@xb,\@yb)}
 {(\tkz@g@xa,\tkz@g@ya)(\tkz@g@xb,\tkz@g@yb)}
 {}{}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}

\part Find:
%from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23290
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:O](0:0){O}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below left:A](230:2){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below right:B](310:2){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:C](90:2){C}
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=5](O,A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\tkzDrawPolygon(C,A,O,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75](A,O,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,font=\small](A,O,B){80\degree}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75](A,C,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,font=\small](A,C,B){$\alpha$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\part Evaluate the unknown arc and angle measures.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] %from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21949
\tkzDefPoint (0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint (2,0){P}
\tkzDefPoint (1,0){C}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](O){$O$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](P){$P$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,1cm)
\tkzDefTangent[from with R=P](O,1cm) \tkzGetPoints{T1}{T2}
\tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 0](O,T1 O,T2 O,P)
\tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 0.5](P,T1 P,T2)
\tkzLabelPoint[above](T1){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](T2){$B$}
\tkzDrawArc[R with nodes,](P,0.5)(T1,T2)
%\draw (T1) node[above right] {$P(\alpha)=(a\,\cos\alpha,a\,\sin\alpha)$};
%\draw (T2) node[below right] {$Q(\alpha)=(a\,\cos\beta,a\,\sin\beta)$};
\draw (P) +(165:0.6) node {$25\degree$};
%\draw (P) +(195:0.6) node {$25\degree$};
\tkzLabelSegment[above right](O,A){$6$ cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved all my issues :)